scicos_new: Wrong value for input argument #2: unable to set "model"
I am developing Xcos block and below is the code of interface file. There are total 3 file .

Interface file
Simulation file
Utils file
The error is with interface file. The code is

// Kalman_Filter_IF.sci
// The interface file for the generic Kalman Filter block.
// This block is externally activated to take measurements data.
// Takes the continuous positions velocity or accelerations as input, adds some 
// errors (noise, scale, nonlinearity, misalignment) and gives
// it as the output.

// Abbrev.
// IF: Inertial Frame, BF: Body Frame, 

// Model input: 
// 2x2 Real - State vector with position and velocity BF w.r.t. IF 
// 1 Real - Covariance vector

// Model output:
// 2x2 Real - Single axis gyro measurement output w.r.t. BF
// 1x1 Real - Error flag
// 0: No error
// 1: Positive saturation error
// 2: Negative saturation error

// Model states:
// 1x1 Real - Random walk error

// Model parameters:
// 2x2 Real - State Vector measurement unit vector w.r.t. BF (Unit vector)
// 1x1 Real - Noise mean (bias) of the sensors
// 1x1 Real - Noise stddev of the sensors
// 1x1 Real - Scale error
// 2x1 Real - Misalignment error 
// 1x1 Real - Random walk error
function [x, y, typ] = Kalman_Filter_IF(job, arg1, arg2)
    funcprot(0);
    x = [];
    y = [];
    typ = [];
    getInputFromSim = 1;
    initial_state = [0.1; 0.0];                 // 2*1 matrix
    initial_covariance = [1.0, 0.0; 0.0, 1.0];  // 2*2 matrix
    
    select job
        // Initialize with mask parameters if any
        case "plot" then
            standard_draw(arg1);
        case "getinputs" then
            [x, y, typ] = standard_inputs(arg1);
        case "getoutputs" then
            [x, y, typ] = standard_outputs(arg1);
        case "getorigin" then
            [x, y] = standard_origin(arg1);

        case 'set' then
            // Assignments here comes after assignments of the execution with the "define" flag 
            x = arg1;  // This line is essential, otherwise gives "Invalid index." error.
            graphics = arg1.graphics;
            exprs = graphics.exprs;
            model = arg1.model;
            
            if getInputFromSim == 1 then
                exec("macros/Kalman_Filter_Utils.sci",-1); // Not sure about this line in MATLAB, comment it if not necessary
                title = "Set Parameter";
                labels = ['Initial state [x_dot(velocity), x(position)] which is position in ECEF frame and velocity'; 
                          'Covariance which gives the uncertainty at position and velocity'];
                // Changed 'Stiffness' to 'Covariance'
                // In future we can add {'Accelerations', 'Orientations which is obation altitude control system'}
                types = list('vec', [2,1], 'mat', [2,2]);  // Changed 'vec' to 'mat' for Covariance
                endLoop = %f;
                // Create a dialog for getting user inputs
                while ~endLoop do
                    // Initialize dialog for parameters and initial state
                    [ok, State, Covariance, exprs] = scicos_getvalue(title, labels, types, exprs);
                    errMsg = [];

                    // Check return set conditions of the initial state as per meetings
                    if ~ok then
                        // depends on what type of data we are having
                        if State>0 // first condition of position and velocity
                            errMsg = ["The velocity is positive [m/s]"];
                        end 

                        if condition2 // second condition of velocity
                            errMsg = [];
                        end

                        if isempty(errMsg) then
                            [model.rpar, isError] = EncodeRpar_KF(model.rpar, State, Covariance);
                            graphics.exprs = exprs;
                            x.graphics = graphics;
                            x.model = model;
                            endLoop = %t;
                            // Check parameters
                            // You can add additional checks for input parameters here if needed

                            // Accept inputs and save them
                        else
                            messagebox(errMsg);
                            error(errMsg, 20000);
                            endLoop = %f;
                        end
                    else
                        warning('Kalman_Filter_IF: Set: Cancel!');
                        endLoop = %t;
                    end
                end
            else
                model.state = [concatAB(initial_state,initial_covariance)];
                model.rpar = initial_covariance;  // Use the covariance matrix as a parameter
                graphics.exprs = exprs;
                x.graphics = graphics;
                x.model = model;
                break
                message("Failed to update block io");
            end
            // Concatenate the covariance matrix to the state vector
            // model.state = [State; Covariance(:)];  // Use the concatenation operator ":" for the matrix
        // Define block properties
        case 'define'
            // Create object
            model = scicos_model();

            // Provide name and type
            model.sim = {'Kalman_Filter_sim', 5}; // what is case 4 and 5? https://help.scilab.org/scicos_model.html
            // Define inputs and outputs
            // One input with a variable-size "double" element
            model.in = [2;2]; // first dimension of the first input whcih is row  2*1 and 2*2 hence it will be [2;2]
            model.in2 = [1;2];   // the second dimension of I/P port is [1;2] from above 
            model.intyp = [1;1];  // all the vector and matrices are real value
            
            model.out = [2;2];  // first dimension of the first output whcih is row  2*1 and 2*2 hence it will be [2;2]
            model.out2 =  [1;2]; // the second dimension of O/P port is [1;2] from above 
            model.outtyp = [1;1];  // all the vector and matrices are real value
            //model.state = [initial_state,matrix(initial_covariance)];   // Use the matrix concatenation operator ":" to convert matrix to column vector          model.state=[State;Covariance]
            model.state = [concatAB(initial_state,initial_covariance)];
            model.rpar = [initial_covariance(:)];  // Use the covariance matrix as a parameter
            // Define block properties
            model.blocktype = "c";
            model.dep_ut = [%t,%f]; // what does %t and %f indicates? true and false

            // Set block properties
            exprs = ["[0.1; 0.0]";"1.0, 0.0; 0.0, 1.0"]; // How do we get this value?
            x = standard_define([4 4], model, exprs);
            x.graphics.style = ['blockWithLabel;displayedLabel=Kalman_Filter'];
            // other cases other than set or define sections
    end
endfunction


The error encounter is
>! Building macros...
>! Creation of [spacecraft_gnc_tbxlib] (Macros) --
>! genlib: Processing file: Common_Utils.sci
>! genlib: Processing file: GravityGradient_Utils.sci
>! genlib: Processing file: Gyroscope_SIM.sci
>! genlib: Processing file: Gyroscope_Utils.sci
>! genlib: Processing file: Kalman_Filter_IF.sci
>! genlib: Processing file: Kalman_Filter_IF.sci~
>! genlib: Processing file: Kalman_Filter_Utils.sci
>! genlib: Processing file: MagneticField_Utils.sci
>! genlib: Processing file: Magnetometer_Utils.sci
>! genlib: Processing file: Magnetorquer_Utils.sci
>! genlib: Processing file: ReactionWheel_Utils.sci
>! genlib: Processing file: RigidBody_Utils.sci
>! genlib: Processing file: StarTracker_Utils.sci
>! Building blocks...
>! at line     8 of function        scicos_block       ( C:\Program Files\scilab-2024.0.0\modules\scicos\macros\scicos_scicos\scicos_block.sci line 29 )
>! at line    29 of function        standard_define    ( C:\Program Files\scilab-2024.0.0\modules\scicos\macros\scicos_scicos\standard_define.sci line 50 )
>! at line   110 of function        Kalman_Filter_IF   ( C:\Users\Vims\Desktop\spacecraft-gnc-tbx\macros\Kalman_Filter_IF.sci line 141 )
>! at line     1 of executed string 
>! at line    78 of function        tbx_build_blocks   ( C:\Program Files\scilab-2024.0.0\modules\modules_manager\macros\tbx_build_blocks.sci line 90 )
>! at line     7 of function        buildmacros        ( C:\Users\Vims\Desktop\spacecraft-gnc-tbx\macros\buildmacros.sce line 10 )
>! at line    14 of executed file   C:\Users\Vims\Desktop\spacecraft-gnc-tbx\macros\buildmacros.sce
>! at line    13 of function        tbx_builder        ( C:\Program Files\scilab-2024.0.0\modules\modules_manager\macros\tbx_builder.sci line 26 )
>! at line    40 of function        tbx_builder_macros ( C:\Program Files\scilab-2024.0.0\modules\modules_manager\macros\tbx_builder_macros.sci line 55 )
>! at line    34 of function        main_builder       ( C:\Users\Vims\Desktop\spacecraft-gnc-tbx\builder.sce line 43 )
>! at line    50 of executed file   C:\Users\Vims\Desktop\spacecraft-gnc-tbx\builder.sce
>! 
>! scicos_new: Wrong value for input argument #2: unable to set "model".

How to deal with such error and standard define function is inbuilt functions which has nothing to do with parameters only Interface file has an error.
The mention function are as below
//  Scicos
//
//  Copyright (C) INRIA - METALAU Project <scicos@inria.fr>
//
// This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
// it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
// the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
// (at your option) any later version.
//
// This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
// but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
// MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
// GNU General Public License for more details.
//
// You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
// along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
// Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301, USA.
//
// See the file ../license.txt
//

function blk=scicos_block(v1,v2,v3,v4)
    //Block data structure initialization
    if exists("graphics","local")==0 then graphics=scicos_graphics(),end
    if exists("model","local")==0 then model=scicos_model(),end
    if exists("gui","local")==0 then gui="",end
    if exists("doc","local")==0 then doc=list(),end

    blk=scicos_new(["Block","graphics","model","gui","doc"],graphics,model,gui,doc)
endfunction

//  Scicos
//
//  Copyright (C) INRIA - METALAU Project <scicos@inria.fr>
//
// This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
// it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
// the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
// (at your option) any later version.
//
// This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
// but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
// MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
// GNU General Public License for more details.
//
// You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
// along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
// Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301, USA.
//
// See the file ../license.txt
//

function o=standard_define(sz,model,label,gr_i)
    //initialize graphic part of the block data structure

    if argn(2)<4 then gr_i=[],end

    nin=size(model.in,1);
    if nin>0 then pin(nin,1)=0,else pin=[],end

    nout=size(model.out,1);
    if nout>0 then pout(nout,1)=0,else pout=[],end

    ncin=size(model.evtin,1);
    if ncin>0 then pein(ncin,1)=0,else pein=[],end

    ncout=size(model.evtout,1);
    if ncout>0 then peout(ncout,1)=0,else peout=[],end

    if type(gr_i)<>15 then gr_i=list(gr_i,8),end
    if gr_i(2)==[] then gr_i(2)=8,end
    if gr_i(2)==0 then gr_i(2)=[],end

    graphics=scicos_graphics(sz=sz,pin=pin,pout=pout,pein=pein,peout=peout, ...
    gr_i=gr_i,exprs=label)

    //  if model.sim(1)=='super' then
    //    o=scicos_block(graphics=graphics,model=model,gui='SUPER_f')
    //  else
    [ln,mc]=where()
    o=scicos_block(graphics=graphics,model=model,gui=mc(2))
    //  end
endfunction



The website is mention it with link model setup for Xcos block
Trying to develop Xcos block and expecting resolve the error. So my block can run properly.
